# Map a new column to a Pandas dataframe by comparing current and previous row of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples, geopy

I am trying to map a new column to a pandas dataframe using a custom function that takes in two input tuples. The function is:

```
def distance(origin, destination):
   lat1, lon1 = origin
   lat2, lon2 = destination
   radius = 3958.8 # miles

   dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
   dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
   a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
    * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
   c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
   d = radius * c

   return d
```

The dataframe has a column of lat and long in tuple form and I am attempting to measure the distance between the current and previous row's coordinates.

I have tried a for loop:

```
df3.loc[0, 'dist'] = 0
for i in range(1, len(df3)):
    df3.loc[i, 'dist'] = distance(df3.loc[i-1, 'lat_long'], df3.loc[i, 'lat_long'])
```

but I get an error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Any ideas on how to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synthesised data to illustrate

1. `reset_index()` to get row number as a column `index`
2. construct a `range()` that is from previous row to current row.  Floored previous row to 0 if it's first row
3. pass list of tuples to `tuplecalc()`.  You noted your long,lat are tuples
4. calc that shows it is taking current and previous row into consideration
5. finally remove synthetic `index` column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"geo":[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]}).reset_index()
def distance(prev, curr):
    return prev[0] + prev[1] + curr[0] + curr[1]
def tuplecalc(tuples):
    return distance(tuples[0], tuples[1] if len(tuples)==2 else (0,0))
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda r: tuplecalc(df.loc[range(max(r["index"]-1,0),r["index"]+1),"geo"].values), axis=1)
df.drop(["index"], axis=1)
```

**as additional columns**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"long":[1,3,5], "lat":[2,4,6]}).reset_index()
def rowrange(index, col):
    return 0 if index==0 else df.loc[range(max(index-1,0),index), col].values[0]
df["prev_long"] = df.apply(lambda r: rowrange(r["index"], "long"), axis=1)
df["prev_lat"] = df.apply(lambda r: rowrange(r["index"], "lat"), axis=1)
df
```

**output**

```
    geo distance
0   (1, 2)  3
1   (3, 4)  10
2   (5, 6)  18
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not able to make it work with your answer.  I have modified it to get it working for my case, but I am getting a generator object returned instead of a value.
I modified the tuplecalc as:
     def tuplecalc(tuples):
         return (distance(t[0], t[1]) for t in tuples)
In an effort to calculate the distance versus adding them together.

Comment: I've slightly amended my answer so I'm not embedding list comprehension in there as well.... I believe your error `return (distance(t[0], t[1]) for t in tuples)` brackets meaning it's returning a tuple not a scalar

Comment: Now the error reads: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". Is there maybe a way to do this without using a tuple?  I have the lat and long coordinates in separate columns of a pandas dataframe.  I combined them thinking it would make it easier. I just need to iterate over the previous row and current row by passing the associated coordinates into the distance function described in my OP.

Comment: added another solution - I provided tuples as you stated tuples in question title.  Have de-normalised them onto same row.  Should be extra simple to work with now :)